# what does 'legend' mean in sql?

Tags: sql

im doing some practice sql problems

one of the questions is:

> Prepare a shipping statement for
>   customer 'C001' it should show the
>   date, the legend 'Delivery' and the
>   total value of the products shipped on
>   each day.

'delivery' is not a table nor is it a column in any table.

what does legend mean??

Comment: what database system? what version?

Comment: In sql, it means a person who seems to know everything about sql

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't mean anything in SQL.  In English it means the label at the top of the column or next to the data that explains what the data is.

In other words, produce a listing showing the customer number, the date, and a column labeled "Delivery" that shows the total value of goods shipped to that customer on that date.

Answer (score 2):

I finally figured this one out.  This is the answer that is accepted as correct.

```
    SELECT sdate, 'delivery', SUM(quantity * price) AS "Total Value"
    FROM shipped
    JOIN product ON (shipped.product = product.id)
    WHERE badguy = 'C001'
    GROUP BY sdate;
```

It is just looking for a column next to the date column with the word "Delivery" in each row. The question was worded in a way that was hard to understand.

Answer (score 1):

In this case I think it means the title for the shipping statement.

From the dictionary -

**Legend**

3 an inscription, esp. on a coin or medal.
• a caption : a picture of a tiger with the legend “Go ahead, make my day.”
• the wording on a map or diagram explaining the symbols used

Answer (score 1):

"Legend" is not strictly speaking an SQL term - but in that case it is used to indicate the name of the column. Somewhat poor naming, since legend actually means overall set of labels/explanations and not a single label